# What is this letter?

Tags: greek, alphabet, inscription

I came across this picture attached to a clickbaity article this morning:

[image: partial abecedary]

A nice, normal-looking Greek alphabet…except for something that looks like `S` in between epsilon and zeta.

What is this letter? The only letter that I can think of for that position is digamma, but I've never seen a digamma in that shape, only like `F`.

Comment: This shape is used for terminal sigma, in contrast to medial; In my (Classical) Greek grammar it is shown for 6;in the Aldine Bible it is used with an extended top bar for monogram ts, (tau sigma); in greek alphabets it is often placed in the position previously occupied by digamma.This is all a preamble to saying it has several names: sigma, terminal sigma, tsau, tsigma, stigma, hex, and digamma.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I'd guess it's the symbol for 6, originally digamma, but later taking on an S-like shape.  (It's a bit hard to make out, but I think the last two cells contain ΙΑ and ΙΒ, indicating a series of 1 to 12.)

Comment: So it's a sundial, perhaps? Would make sense with the needle in the middle of the circle.

Comment: That would be my guess.

Comment: @Arthur there's little doubt that it is one. In antiquity it was common to count 12 hours from sunrise to sunset

Answer (score 5):

It is indeed one of the forms of Digamma, the form particularly used as a numeral. See [Here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digamma)